# Application takes long time during startup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, startup

I have a Windows application written in C# which takes long time during startup. The time to enter the `Main()` method is more than a minute. The following assemblies are being used in my project:

```
<Reference Include="PresentationCore">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
<Reference Include="UIAutomationProvider">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WindowsBase">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Main:

```
static class AppMain
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        bool bCreatedNew = true;

        using (new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "AppMutex", out bCreatedNew))
        {
            if (bCreatedNew)
            {
                TextWriterTraceListener traceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(File.AppendText("./applog.txt"));
                Trace.Listeners.Add(traceListener);
                Trace.AutoFlush = true;

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }
            else
            {
                Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName))
                {
                    if (process.Id != currentProcess.Id)
                    {
                        if (SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle) == false)
                            MessageBox.Show("Failed to set to foreground..", "Warming", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How could I overcome this issue?

Comment: Is there a lot of setup being done before Application.Run is called (or whatever the entrance to your Main is)?

Comment: Please find the updated the code in main().

Comment: You can profile the application.

Comment: Do you invoke it from the IDE or from command line? Is it compiled in debug or release? I suspect the loading time is related to loading symbols in the IDE or something like this...

Comment: References themselves don't affect startup time, since assemblies are loaded on demand.

Comment: @Yuval I am invoking it from the commandline. It is a release binary

Answer (score 2):

You need to find strategies to narrow down the problem.

Try loading a release build outside the debugger to get a real indication of the speed. Often delays in debug versions or when running under a debugger are not present in release.

Reduce the problem by trying parts of the code in isolation - e.g. Comment out the mutex to see if the problem is loading the dlls or the startup logic.

Put some trace in to tell you what the program is doing. On each trace, dump out the Environment.TickCount so you can work out which bit of code is taking the time.

Long delays, especially multiples of 30 seconds, are often due to resource time-outs - is anything being accessed over a network connection or similar that might be slow our unavailable? It could be as simple as the current directory being set somewhere unhelpful so opening the trace file in the current directory is stalling - try a full path instead of './'

Comment: I have added few trace statements and noticed that the delay was observed before entering main()..

Comment: What if you have an empty Main() function? Do you still see the slow load time?